# How to handle potentially Domain (integration) events order messed up?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Lets take basic example with bounded contexts: `Ordering`, `Payment`, `Shipping`.
Lets assume that `Order` has a `Order.Status` field which reflects `PaymentProcessed` event from `Payment` BC and `OrderShipped` from `Shipping` BC.

Naturally, shipment happens after payment but it could be that `PaymentProcessed` arrives to `Order` BC later than `OrderShipped` which would end up having `Order.Status` set to `Payed` when in fact its already shipped.

How to handle that? Should `Order` BC have some kind of a state machine with allowed state transitions so that `Payed` could never overwrite `Shipped` or is there some other way to handle it?

Comment: "Should Order BC have some kind of a state machine with allowed state transitions" -- yup.

Comment: When event 2 arrives before 1. Should event 2 fail, 1 be applied and 2 retried? Otherwise you would miss the business event.

Comment: You've to do what's called even brainstorming. Is the sequence of the events really correct? As said @pakspul, could it be that you've to put the order in an idle state and do retry the shipping after you've got the payment. But, if you're event sequence really allows this combination, then you've to think how to handle this with a kind of transition. Or, you could define 2 states, one for the payment and one for the shipping. It depends all on the way you want to manage them.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot avoid that, you should manage it.
When handling the `PaymentProcessed` event you should check if the shipped one already arrive, and behave appropriately (this depends on your domain).
A state machine is one of the way to implement this, but I think the important thing is that your logic expect that they can be out of order.

Comment: yes yes, sure, domain logic is safe: actual shipment can never be handled before payment is done (because `Shipping` BC triggers shipment only when it receives `PaymentProcessed` event. The question is purely about maintaining current state in `Order` BC.

Comment: I meant in the Order BC you should have the logic to handle PaymentProcessed that should expect that the ship event was already arrived